# Is there a better way of doing 'element[0]'

Tags: angularjs

In my link function of my directives, I'm having to do element[0] to select the actual element. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

For example, my directive is `<canvas my-directive></canvas>`.

```
var link = function (scope, element) {
  var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
  // Maybe something like element.first().getContext('2d') instead?
};
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. That's how it works :) The element that's being injected is from jqLite that angular uses (if you're not using jQuery with you angular application). And that's just how jQuery/jqLite returns - you get an array with the elements, even if there's only one element

Comment: I see. But in what circumstances would I get more than 1 element in the array?

Comment: You won't in your case. But it's a jquery/jqlite wrapper, which is an array.

Comment: @Thomca if you're selector would be like `$('.someClass')` (with jQuery) and you have more than 1 element in the DOM with `someClass`